# Which programmer circuit works with PIC16f877A?

Tags: pic, programmer

I'm having the PIC16F877A microntroller.I dont have the programing hardware.I want to make it on my own.For that I need the programmer circuit.Please help me construct my own programmer else suggest me the website which contains programmer circuit specifically for PIC16F877A.

Comment: Are you suggesting that we use Google to find it?

Comment: Has it occurred to you that you're probably going to need a programmer to program any programmer that you might build?

Comment: I don't recommend it- buy a PICKit, but there is a serial port driven programmer design floating around. If you can find a serial port in 2015.

Answer (score 1):

All of my PIC programmers except the LProg support the 16F877A.  This includes the [USBProg2](http://www.embedinc.com/products/usbprog2/index.htm), and the discontinued [USBProg](http://www.embedinc.com/products/usbprog/index.htm), [ProProg](http://www.embedinc.com/proprog/index.htm), and [EasyProg](http://www.embedinc.com/easyprog/index.htm).

The schematic of each of them is available from their respective product pages.  The HEX files for the latest version of each of these is included in the Operational Software release, and the source code for at least one of them is included in the Development Software release.  OK, I just checked.  Both the EasyProg and USBProg (and USBProg2, same firmware) firmware is included in the Development Software release.  The EasyProg code hasn't been touched since 2007, so there is a good chance the build environment and common firmware resources have changed so that it won't build anymore without a little work to update it to the latest environment.

If you plan to make your own programmer, you should consider having it adhere to my [PIC Programmer Protocol](http://www.embedinc.com/picprg/picprg_prot.txt.htm).  This is the one common protocol used by all my programmers to communicate to the host.  It probably looks more complicated than it is.  Many of the commands are optional.  You can implement a small subset of the overall commands if you only intend to support a particular known PIC.  However, by using my protocol you can test and run your programmer with known working host software.  I sortof remember that someone even created firmware for one of Wouter's Wisp programmers that adhered to my protocol and therefore worked with my host programs, like PIC_PROG, PIC_READ, and PIC_CTRL.

Another thing to consider is to use a newer PIC.  The 16F877A is pretty old.  Some of the newer PICs have the same footprint but have a simpler hardware programming interface that allows all 3.3 V operation.  Take a look at the 16F1xxx, 18FxxJyy, and 18FxxKyy families.  The simpler programming interface can be driven by a much simpler programmer circuit, which is what the [LProg](http://www.embedinc.com/products/lprog/index.htm) is all about.  Of course at only $20 for the LProg from MicrochipDirect, it's hard for even a hobbyist to justify building their own.

Answer (score 0):

The [Wisp648](http://www.voti.nl/wisp648/) kit supports this chip. All its circuits are in the [manual](http://www.voti.nl/wisp648/wisp648.pdf), and the [sourcecode](http://www.voti.nl/wisp648/wisp648.hex) of the PIC inside is available as well. You can buy the kit, buy a built Wisp648 or just buy the programmed PIC inside (if you don't have a programmer to program it with).